# usb flash drive and external hard drive won't appear in windows 11

Tags: windows, usb, external-hard-drive, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

After upgrading windows 10 to windows 11 the usb flash drives and my external hard drive won't appear in the file explorer and the windows not playing the sound of something is plugged in.
but my optical usb mouse is working on all usb ports.
I tried these fixes but nothing is fixed yet:

1. Run the Troubleshooters by running this command: `msdt.exe -id DeviceDiagnostic`
2. Disable USB selective suspend setting
3. Try Another USB Port (or Another PC : is that pc all working fine but in windows 10 not 11)
   and thank you.

Comment: Try getting new drivers.

Comment: i did check for updates but nothing happened.

Comment: did you try the answer from here: https://superuser.com/questions/1706447/d-drive-missing-after-windows-11-upgrade ?