# D:\ Drive Missing after Windows 11 upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive, windows-11

I have recently upgraded to Windows 11 from Windows 10, on a 'HP Pavilion 590-p0063na' Desktop.  Since doing this, I have been unable to locate the 'D:' Drive.  This absent drive, is also preventing me from being able to successfully boot an external hard drive to the Desktop; which is my current goal.

There are no issues with the USB Ports, as I have used the USB Ports, which are able to successfully recognise peripherals; such as the Mouse and Keyboard.

I am able to successfully access the external hard drive, via other devices.  Therefore, there are no issues with the hard drive itself.

I then went into 'Computer Management > Storage > Disk Management', where it appears the hard drive is being recognised.  I cannot be 100% certain, but 'Disk 0 Partition 1' and 'Disk 0 Partition 2' entries are present, when the hard drive is connected.  These entries disappear, when I remove the external hard drive, hence the assumption.

I have also had an additional SSD installed, which accompanies the originally installed HDD.

Ultimately, I just want to access the data on the external hard drive.  Any ideas on how I can get back this 'D:' Drive, which will allow me to achieve this goal?  Also, any ideas what could had removed this drive?

**Screenshots**

- Device Manager:

As you can see, both HHD and the SSD are appearing within the Device Manager window.

I have since noticed that there are two PCL entries, under 'Other Devices', with an exclamation mark.  A quick online search, indicates this could be related to a network issue.  Could this be causing the issue?

[image]

- Computer Management:
  The highlighted entries, are what appear when I connect the external HHD ...

[image]

- My PC:
  The D Drive is completely missing from the 'My PC' area.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide screenshots.  Your question is not clear.  Are you within 10 days of migrating to Windows 11? If you are I would run the following command to extend that window to 30 days.  `DISM /Online /Set-OSUninstallWindow /Value:30`

Comment: I have added a couple of screenshots.  Hopefully, they offer a little more insight into the issue.  It was not a migration.  I switched on the computer, where a `Boot Device Not Found` message appeared.  I then sent it in for repair.  I am not sure if Windows 10 was installed and then upgraded or whether Windows 11 was solely installed upon a complete wipe of the computer.

Comment: So, an external drive isn't showing up on a specific computer, but it works connected to other devices? While info is good, it seems most of the info and description are extraneous and serves to distract and confuse rather than illumine and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem.  The solution, is as follows (for windows 11):

**Step One:**

Head into `Computer Management > Storage > Disk Management`, as highlighted in the below screenshot:

[image]

**Step Two:**

Right Click on the missing Drive and select 'Change Drive Letter and Paths ...' and then simply add, change or remove as required.